# Simple loop with subset and variable name assignment

Tags: r, loops, filter, dplyr, subset

I am actually learning R and I don't understand why this simple assignment does not works. I would like to subset by year using the filter function of the *dplyr* package. After several tentatives, here are a reproducible example using the **gapminder** dataset.

I could use the subset function, lapply, or even anonymous function to solve this problem, but here, I just want to understand why this specific code is not working.

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)

for (i in unique(gapminder$year)) {
paste0("gapminder", i) <- print(gapminder %>%
         filter(year == i))
}
```

With or without print, same problem

Comment: your second example doesn't work because you have an extra close bracket.

Comment: Ohhh Thank you! half of the problem wasn't a problem then. I am going to edit the question, no one is interest in extra bracket issue...

Comment: There is no code like this in R. you cannot if paste canot be used on the left hand side of assignment function. ie there is no function like `\`paste0<-\`` in R, so this is impossible. You would rather use the `assign` function which is equivalent to `<-`. This can be done as `assign(paste0("gapminder", i),gapminder %>%
         filter(year == i))`. But this is not the best way to do it. You can rather `split` your data with year. ie `split(gapminder,gapminder$year)` then set the names by using `setNames` then list to the environment by sing `list2env(...,.GlobalEnv)`. But no need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your assignment is to a function (`paste0`).

If you remove that part it prints each filtered dataframe:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)

for (i in unique(gapminder$year)) {
  print(gapminder %>% filter(year == i))
}
```

You could assign each to a `list`, like so:

```
my_list <- list()

library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)

for (i in seq_along(unique(gapminder$year))) {
  year_filter <- unique(gapminder$year)[i] # each iteration we get another year
  my_list[[i]] <- gapminder %>% filter(year == year_filter)
  cat(paste0("gapminder", year_filter, " ")) # use cat if you want to print at each iteration
}
```

`paste0` just concatenates vectors after converting to character.

Comment: I didn't even noticed that I was assigning to a function... Thank you that was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use **assign** function to store the output.

```
for (i in unique(gapminder$year)) 
{
    assign(paste0("gapminder", i),print(gapminder %>%filter(year == i)))
}
```

If you want to get the specific output, use **get** function.

```
out_i = get(paste0("gapminder", i))
```